# Bootstrap dropdown conflicting with jQuery.dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to manually toggle a bootstrap dropdown. This script used to work until recently:

```
$(function () {
    $('.role-toggler').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

However when I try click the dropdown now I get:

> Uncaught Error: Method toggle does not exists on jQuery.dropdown

I am using [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design), [Bootstrap 3.3.6](http://getbootstrap.com/) and jQuery 2.1.4. I recently updated my packages which included bootstrap and jquery, which may have caused this issue.

Comment: try removing jquery ui plugin and see if it works.

Comment: I don't use the jquery ui plugin

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that Bootstrap material design is now using a custom jQuery [dropdown plugin](https://github.com/FezVrasta/dropdown.js) which overwrites the bootstrap drowpdown but has a different minimal API.

Try raising an [issue](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/) mentioning that you expect a bootstrap like API since its a bootstrap theme.